# Estimating water quality statistics using multiple sites

Tags: multilevel-analysis, monitoring

I have a typical water quality data set, containing a number of sites sampled across a couple of years, generally on a monthly timescale.

I want to estimate the 80th %ile for setting water quality objectives, which is fairly easy on a site by site basis. However, how can I do this where certain sites might be aggregated to provide a better estimate of population statistic at these locations? (i.e. where several sites are similar and in the same waterway section).

I was thinking some kind of hierarchical approach, with Sample events linking to Sites linking to a single replicate at each site for each parameter.

Does that sound reasonable? Another approach is simply to average the results for all the sites on each occasion, and just use that average in the data to determine percentiles.

Thanks for your help anyone.
Cheers

Comment: You might need a slightly more complicated model, one that accounts for spatial autocorrelation across all your sites.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking that could be a problem in closer sites, and perhaps the reason to classify sites by location. 
So if we were talking an ANOVA factorial type model (I'm trying to remember my terms) we'd have the following:
- sites
- nested within location (a number of locations, each with separate sites)
- nested within sample events (by month say).

Does this account for spatial autocorrelation?

Even if it does I'm still a little hazy about how to implement, since I'm looking for percentiles rather than the mean, so perhaps a distribution free method.